# Import png image in android studio

Tags: android, image, android-studio, png

I'm trying to import a png image into android studio.
I'm following these steps: res->drawable->new image assets->action bar and tab icons, the problem is that android studio creates 4 images and the biggest of these is 96x96 (it's hard to see on the app) while the original image is 1000x1000, so my question is how can I import and display a 1000x1000 png image?

Comment: open the app in explorer and go to the res/drawable folder. put the image in there. icons arent 1000x1000...android studio resizes this as icons....

Comment: You are trying to use a 1000x1000 image as an action bar tab icon? You do know that is going to be very inefficient memory wise and could cause app lag right?

Comment: @tyczj I have used that method because is the only one that I know, but icon is a logo for the splash screen

Comment: @DroiDev I can't drag and drop the image

Comment: yes you can. best to look up videos on how to do it, bc yes you can. dont drag it into android studio, drag it into the finder winder (mac) or explorer (windows)

Comment: @DroiDev you're right, thanks!